# get all paragraphs id in an html page

Tags: javascript

I have three paragraphs `<p>`, and I want to display their `id` value in a `textarea`, and this is the code I used :

```
var pNodesList = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var text = "";

var pArrayList = Array.prototype.slice.call(pNodesList);

pArrayList.forEach(function(value, index){
    text += value.getAttribute('id') + String.fromCharCode(13);
});

document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = text;
```

The probelm is when I click on that button, this is the result I get in my `textarea` :

```
myP1
null
myP2
null
myP3
```

Why I'm getting those null values ?

## Edit :

This is my HTML :

```
<p id="myP1" style="font-weight:bold;">
        Ceci est une paragraphe avec deux balises &lt;ul&gt;
        <br>
        <ul>Liste 1 : </ul>
        <ul>Liste 2 : </ul>
    </p>
    <p id="myP2" style="font-weight:bold;">
        Ceci est une paragraphe avec une balise &lt;ul&gt;
        <br>
        <ul>Liste 3 : </ul>
</p>
<p id="myP3" style="font-weight:bold;">Ceci est une paragraphe simple.</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have paragraphs without an attribute `id` when queried by `getAttribute`, it returns `null`.

**UPDATE**: You put an ul inside a paragraph which is forbidden by [HTML specification](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

Comment: No, I don't have any other paragraphs, I only have three paragraphs as I mentioned.

Comment: I think it's 5 times, but It should loop just for 3 times

Comment: Please, check the modification I made to my post, I've posted my HTML code there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid printing the ones that don't have an ID:

```
pArrayList.forEach(function(value, index){
  var id = value.getAttribute('id');
  if (id != null)
    text += value.getAttribute('id') + String.fromCharCode(13);
  });
(a == null)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know why I'm getting null values, even that I don't have any other paragraphs, besides those three I mentioned.